# Reactjs not Rendering view define in foreach loop

Tags: reactjs, loops

I am fetching data from `firebase` and set the data using `useState`, but when I am looping through in component return not viewing anything in the loop. Here is my code.

```
function App() {
const regRef = ref(database, "Tasks/");
const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([{ title: "Task List" }]);

useEffect(() => {
onValue(regRef, (snapshot) => {
  snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
    childSnapshot.forEach((task) => {
      setTasks((oldTasks) => [...oldTasks, task.val()]);
    });
  });
});
}, []);

return (
<div className="App">
  <div>Rendering data</div>
  {tasks.forEach(function (task) {
    console.log("rendering value: " + task.title);
    return (
      <>
        <h2>{task.title}</h2>
        <h4>{task.description}</h4>
      </>
    );
  })}
</div>
);
}
```

In this view, there is only Rendering data div, but in `console log` I am getting all the value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Problem**
`forEach` just iterate the array it doesn't return anything. That's why you can't see anything. Because it doesn't returning anything

**Solve**
Try this. Because `map` returns an array.

```js
{tasks.map(function (task) {
  console.log("rendering value: " + task.title);
  return (
    <>
      <h2>{task.title}</h2>
      <h4>{task.description}</h4>
    </>
  );
})}
```

Comment: Yes, got your point, thanks